# Display limited repeat values in one pdf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, repeat

Is there any way of limiting the displayed repeat values in one page? 
Ex: Display first two values in first page, next two values in the next page etc ?

I tried to find a way of doing this but I could not find anything helpful.

Comment: Have you tried some of the CSS techniques such as `page-break-after:always` as described in the answers to [pageblocktable rows spanning over page breaks when rendered as pdf](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/pageblocktable-rows-spanning-over-page-breaks-when-rendered-as-pdf)?

Comment: Yes but it does not work :(

Comment: It doesn't have a proper answer.

Comment: @Butterfly - Just because it does not yet have an answer does not mean you should create a new question asking the exact same thing.....

Comment: Why  css like {page-break-inside: avoid;} or {page-break-after:always } are not working . It should work.  please check on that.

Comment: @AnkitKhandelwal it works fine! but i'm thinking of a way I can limit the break after every 2 elements. Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: @Eric it works fine! but i'm thinking of a way I can limit the break after every 2 elements. Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: @Butterfly - based on your comments to others, it sounds as though you've not looked at the resource material I've pointed you to in my answer. You can count your elements during page composition via a controller to do what you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do requires a creating a controller that prepares pages for pagination based on the number of lines that are generated for each page (before sending them to the page for output) as described in [Creating Professional PDF Documents with CSS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce).